# Q: Echarts - different background color for different days in the week (time x-axis)

Tags: echarts

I have a graph with different line series where time is the x-axis. I want to colour the backround per day. Alternating colours for weekdays and a different colour on weekends. Been looking into both splitArea and markArea, but none seems to offer the option to colour based on day in week (some formatter that takes in x-axis value would be great).

Somethink like this:

```
Monday - Light
Tuesday - Dark
Wednesday - Light
Thursday - Dark
Friday - Light
Saturday - Dark2
Sunday  - Dark2
```

Comment: Just to make it clear. The graph is showing a user defined time range. I cannot assume there are exactly 7 days and the the first 1/7 is sunday or any such assumptions. The method for selecting color must be based on the x-axis value only.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [xAxis.splitArea.areaStyle.color](https://echarts.apache.org/option.html#xAxis.splitArea.areaStyle) to be an array like `['#eee', '#222', '#eee', '#222', '#eee', '#222', '#222']`.

Comment: I looked into this, but how do I calculate the splits to match the weekdays for an arbitraty length of time. The graph shows a user defined range of data (not fixed length, and fixed number of days) so I have to make it dynamic and data driven.

Comment: @Paaland Maybe you should try with https://echarts.apache.org/option.html#series-line.markArea Here are some examples: http://gallery.echartsjs.com/explore.html#components=markArea~sort=rank~timeframe=all~author=all

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I'm still no closer. This is as far as I get: http://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xHkLCQ7EvQ&v=3 but I'm unable to select which colours the various markAreas get. I want alternating colors, but different shades of the starting color.